# Find ID on separate sheet using part of data in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

Sheet1

```
|Header1|Header3|
|L/F M  |Blank  |
|L/F M  |Blank  |
|L/F M  |Blank  |
|L/F M  |Blank  |
|L/F M  |Blank  |
|L/F M  |Blank  |
```

Sheet2

```
|Header1|Header2|
|ID     |F L    |
|ID     |F L    |
|ID     |F L    |
|ID     |F L    |
|ID     |F L    |
|ID     |F L    |

F = First Name
M = Middle Name
L = Last Name
```

The objective is to run a script that will take either the first name or last name from sheet1 and compare with the coresponding names in sheet2. When a match is found, it will place the ID value in the blank cell next to it.

```
Option Explicit

Dim fName As Range

Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I:I")
         Set fName = .Find(what:=Left(Target, InStr(Target, "/")), LookAt:=xlPart)
    End With

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:E")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Intersect(Target, Range("E:E"))
            .Offset(, -7).Value = fName.Value
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

I have been trying to adjust this code to no success.

Comment: Does this have to be VBA? It looks like this could be done with a formula

Comment: Are there no middle names in sheet2?  Are the first and last names in sheet2 separated by a single space? Are the last/first names on sheet1 separated only by slash and not space(s)?

Comment: @tigeravatar Yes, that is ture, however, initially, the information is split between sperate workbooks hence the variance in the names and the order they are being provided. A little down the road I intend to modify the script to extract and import data from those sheets.

Comment: @JohnMuggins Sheet2 does not have middle names and are separated by a single space. Sheet1 has a "/" and no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

if your sheet 1 looks like this:

```
Miller/John Brent
Acme/Joan Alice
Jones/Beatrice Sally
```

And your sheet 2 looks like this

```
ID 101  John Miller
ID 102  Joan Acme
ID 103  Beatrice Jones
```

Then the following code can help you learn the split function.  Once you learn how to get the first and last name from sheet 1 you will be able to search for it on sheet2 and get the corresponding ID number

```
Sub getID()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim arraySheet2, arraySheet1_a, arraySheet1_b

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

For i = 1 To 3
    arraySheet1_a = Split(ws1.Range("A" & i).Value, "/")
    arraySheet1_b = Split(arraySheet1_a(1), " ")
Debug.Print arraySheet1_b(0) & " " & arraySheet1_a(0)
Next i

Debug.Print "   "


For i = 1 To 3
    arraySheet2 = Split(ws2.Range("B" & i).Value, " ")
Debug.Print arraySheet2(0) & " " & arraySheet2(1)
Next i

Set ws1 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I am struggling with getting this macro running. Initially I tried adapting it to     Sub CommandButton1_Click()    but it didnt like that. So i tried to attach it to a module and call the module through a click of a button. Nothing happened... and the same goes if I try and squeeze it into a worksheet change.

Comment: The important thing is the logic.  Do you see the logic with the "Split" function?  Sheet1 is initially split by the "/" forward slash character into a variable called   arraySheet1_a.  This gives you an array.  arraySheet1_a(0) = "Miller" and arraySheet1_a(1) = "John Brent".  So now we split arraySheet1_a(1) into another array,   arraySheet1_b, where arraySheet1_b(0) = "John" and arraySheet1_b(1) = "Brent".  So now you can search your other sheet for .find(what:=arraySheet1_b(0) & " " & arraySheet1_a(0)) ----- which equals "John Miller".  Don't forget the space between the two names.